# Colorbox and ASP.NET in a bound Datalist

Tags: asp.net, colorbox, datalist

My images are stored in a SQL database. I bind to the table and use the generated image control and a ashx handler. No problem. I now have the thumbnail image surrounded by a anchor tag. The problem come in finding the large image thats in a hidden div and display ONLY that.. I don't want a gallery just that one image. If you are reading this you know that datalists when generating their controls assigns mangled ID's to their components. How can I address that image from my thumbnail image?

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <a class="colorme" href="#">Actual thumbnail image</a>
       <div style="display:none">
          <div id="colorme" runat="server">Actual image to display            
          </div>
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

ASP.NET 4.0 no master page.

Answer (score 0):

Assign ID and run at server for your Image and use
`<%= yourimage.ClientID %>` this will return that particular image wherever you'll use it..not the mangled IDs generated by Datalist control.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use jQuery, and find the element using the [next-sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/).

```
$(".colorme").click(function(){
    $(this).find("~ div").show();
});
```

This would work no matter how many images you have on the page.